# How to get leading zeroes to show in excel using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a input text file with zip codes and other information on it. I'm using VBScript to parse it and write the information into a spreadsheet. The zip codes that start with 0 are being cut to 4 numbers. For example 05125 in the text file is 5125 in the excel file.

Please don't recommend switching to any other coding language because the tool has already been created in VBScript, the only issue is the leading zeroes disappear.

I'm using

```
Set objReadFile = objFileSys.OpenTextFile(importLocation & checkname, 1)
Set objOutFile = objFileSys.CreateTextFile(exportLocation & checkname1, True) 
do until objReadFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objReadFile.ReadLine()
MailingZipCode = mid(strLine, 295, 9)
blob = ALL THE EXTRA DATA & "," & MailingZipCode & "," & 
objOutFile.Writeline blob
```

to create the output file and read the zip code from the input file.
When I put "'" before mid(strLine, 295, 9) it actually prints the apostrophe which unfortunately the client doesn't want. I wish they did as this whole thread wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: You will need to format the cells in which the values are to be placed as Text before assigning the values.

Comment: @ScottCraner I create the output file in the VBScript code, so it doesn't exist until the script is running. Is this something I can do within the code?

Comment: Gotta love New Jersey.  ...What's the code you're using to create the output file, specifically, the part where it's entering your zip codes?  You may try to set those to like `zipCode = "'" & Range(A1)`.?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the code you are using.   You will need to create the file then format the cells then assign the values.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm new to SO so I didn't know how to add two users to one comment, anyway the above comment should answer your question. Thanks

Comment: Please put the code in the original post using [edit].  do not use comments for clarification.

Comment: @ScottCraner, done

Comment: And how are you assigning `MailingZipCode` to Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner changes above

Comment: Okay, now I do not see what this has to do with excel, I see how you are creating a text file, but your code does not use excel.  so what is your question?  It should do what you want by creating a text file with the appropriate leading `0`s.  So you question is really how do you open a text file in Excel to keep the leading `0`s.  this question does not have anything to do with vbscript.  Because it has to do how the end user of the text file opens it in excel.  They will need to open an empty xls, then use the import wizard and denote that column as text.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm trying to post as much code as I can for my question to make sense without posting confidential info. The output file that is created is a CSV which yes is essentially a text file but as I'm sure you know can also be opened as a spreadsheet. When opened up as a text file the 0 shows in the zip code but when opened as an excel spreadsheet, no zero..if I'm not giving enough information and code I apologize

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok I see what you're saying, the end user basically would have to do that extra step. I guess my question was is there any padding technique I can use in VBScript so they WON'T have to do that step?

Comment: No,  the only thing you can do is to actually create an .XLSX instead of .CSV and send that instead.

Comment: @ScottCraner okay thank you